# How redirect subdomains to multiple controllers on Rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes, subdomain, ruby-on-rails-4

I have Agent and Brand in my Rails 4 app (an Agent has many :brands), and each one have a :subdomain field.

So I want to have:

```
- agentsubdomain.domain.com (should redirect to 'agents#show')
- brandsubdomain.domain.com (should redirect to 'agents/brands#show')
```

I'm trying to do this in routes.rb:

```
resources :agents do
    resources :brands, module: 'agents'
end

get '/', to: 'agents/brands#show', 
    constraints: lambda { |r| r.subdomain.present? && r.subdomain != 'www' }
get '/', to: 'agents#show', 
    constraints: lambda { |r| r.subdomain.present? && r.subdomain != 'www' }

root 'home#index'
```

That obviously doesn't work because only the first '/' is matched, always going to brands#show.

How can I redirect to agents#show OR agents/brands#show, depending on which one exists?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a routes_helper.rb module. In it create 2 methods one called "agents_brands_present?" and one called "agents_present?" then have them receive the request object as a parameter and check if the appropriate subdomains exist.

```
require 'RoutesHelper'
get '/', to: 'agents/brands#show', 
    constraints: lambda { |r| r.subdomain.present? && RoutesHelper.agents_brand_present?(r) && r.subdomain != 'www' }
get '/', to: 'agents#show', 
    constraints: lambda { |r| r.subdomain.agents_present? && RoutesHelper.agents_present?(r) && r.subdomain != 'www' }
```